# How to access the folder name from the directory

Tags: java

I want to get the name of the folders from directory who only have .c and .h files.
below is my code but I am not getting that how exactly I can get the folder names who only have .c and .h files.

```
File directory = new File(directoryName);
        //get all the files from a directory

        if(directory.exists()){
        File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : fList){
            if (file.isDirectory()){
                System.out.println(file.getName());
                System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
```

Above code will take the input path for directory and prints the name of all sub folders or sub directories if the main directory is exist.and also prints the path.Now I only want the name of all sub folders from directory which have .c and .h files.
Thanks If anyone help me.

Comment: Can the files be nested deeper than first level below root? i.e. like `root -> folder1 -> folder2 -> file.c` ?

Comment: yes ...It is deeper or nested

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look at Apache's DirectoryScanner

Using that we can mention the file extension types to be considered/omitted

```
DirectoryScanner scanner = new DirectoryScanner();
scanner.setIncludes(new String[]{"*.c", "*.h"});
```

https://ant.apache.org/manual/api/org/apache/tools/ant/DirectoryScanner.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list and `getParent()` function like:

```
List<String> list;
File directory = new File(directoryName);

if(directory.exists()){
   File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
   for (File file : fList){
     if (file.isDirectory()){
        System.out.println(file.getName());
        if(file.getName().contains(".c") || file.getName().contains(".h"))
           list.add(file.getParent());
        System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath());
     }
   }
}

for(String item : list) {
   System.out.println(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've given a pure Java solution here, but if your directory structure is too deep or directories have thousands of files, this may not work out. In that case you may have to run an OS command and dump the output into Java. For instance if you use Unix (or Unix-based) system, you can use `find` to list directories and invoke the command from Java using [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Now the Java solution:

Create a custom [FileNameFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FilenameFilter.html) first. This will filter files based on extensions you pass.

```
public class ExtensionFilter implements FilenameFilter {
    private String[] extensions;

    public ExtensionFilter(String... extensions) {
        this.extensions = extensions;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
        for (String extension : extensions) {
            if ( name.toLowerCase().endsWith(extension.toLowerCase()) ) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Create a [FileFilter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html) to help you filter for only directories (for recursion)

```
public class FolderFilter implements FileFilter {
    @Override
    public boolean accept(File path) {
        return path.isDirectory();
    }
}
```

Use recursion to build list of folder paths contains files with the given extension.

```
private static final FolderFilter folderFilter = new FolderFilter();

public List<String> recursiveSearch(File base, ExtensionFilter extFilter) {
        List<String> paths = new ArrayList<>();
        //Does current directory itself have files of given extension?
        if (base.list(extFilter).length > 0) { 
            paths.add(base.getPath()); //Use base.getName() here instead, for just name
        }
        // Recurse through current directory's subfolders
        for (File dir : base.listFiles(folderFilter)) {
            paths.addAll(recurse(dir, extFilter));
        }
        return paths;
}
```

Finally, invoke it like so:

```
String basePath = "...";
File baseDir = new File(basePath);
ExtensionFilter extFilter = new ExtensionFilter(".c",".h");
List<String> folders = recurse(baseDir, extFilter);
```

This will now contain all paths (or names as mentioned above) of folders which have files with given extensions.